# JSON object in data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json, custom-data-attribute

Can we somehow write a JSON string in html data tag attribute?

Then process it in javascript to parse as a normal JSON object.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<select class="field" data-select="{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}"></select>
```

**JS**

```
var obj = JSON.parse($('form').find('select').attr('data-select'));
```

Solution using single quotes:

```
<select class="field" data-select='{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}'></select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify (if javascript) to make the json a string and sotre it in the data-* field.

```
var json = {"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]};
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
div.setAttribute("data-json", JSON.stringify(json));
alert(div.getAttribute("data-json"))
```

Check the template engine docs  (if you are you are using one) to generate the stringified json.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1tqxhty/

Comment: Was needed only single quotes in wrapping string of "data-select" attribute.